# python-docx - add a table in the end of the document

Tags: python, python-docx

I have to add a table in the end of each document. But the text never finish in the end of the document.

Is there any tips how to append this table at the end of the document? Thnx

```
txt = ["xxxxxx","yyyyyy","zzzzzz"]
d = Document(os.path.join(path,i))
table = d.add_table(rows=3, cols=1)
for j in range(3):
    row = table.rows[j]
    row.cells[0].text = txt[j]
d.save(os.path.join(path,i))
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I cannot understand your problem. Can you please provide what is the output, and what would you want to be the output?

Comment: It is added a table with 3 rows filled with txt list at the last paragraph. I need this table at the end of the document. The last paragraph does not mean it is the end of the document. Thnx for reply

Comment: It is at the of the document, according to your picture. What would you want to do?

Comment: @Florjan i believe you're asking how to stick that table to the bottom of the page right?

Comment: Yes Alex, thats the point. Im not finding anything in the official documentation. I can loop through paragraphs but not in the end of the page.